# Wrong output - Ramanujan's approximation of factorial and C++

Tags: c++, factorial

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n, k, g;
    float fact;

    cin >> n;

    fact = sqrt(3.14159265359)*pow(n/2.7182818284, n);
    fact *= pow(((8*n + 4)*n + 1)*n + (float)1/30, (float)1/6);

    k=floor(fact);

    g=k%1000000000;

    cout << g << "\n";
    
};
```

My program calculates value of n! modulo 1000000000. For small values of n, it works good. But for larger ones, it constantly outputs -147483648. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By Stack Exchange policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

This is an overflow problem on your variable `fact`, you get over the max of what a `float` can hold.

Actually even larger types as `long double` and `long long int` will not hold those huge values, you need larger larger types.

I suggest to resolve it by looping 1 to n, multiplying at each iteration and applying mod too. This will keep the number small.

Ramanujan’s factorial approximation will not help you here because it does not consider the mod advantage, you may try [Wilsom Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)

Comment: Great, so which datatype should I use? My C++ textbook especially recommends floats for such purposes.

Comment: Exactly 1 000 000 000.

Comment: You should include the mod caculation before the factorial get bigger, 100000000! is not just large.

Comment: So what should it look like?

Comment: You should made it as a loop 1 to n, everytime you multiply a number, you do the mod.

Comment: But there's the problem. I'm not computing factorial by multiplying all numbers from 1 to n, I'm approximationg it, as multiplying takes too much time.

Comment: try the types `long double` and `long  long int`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98448/discussion-between-bigother-and-hetajr).